# ASP.NET URL Rewriting confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have not previously done any URL rewriting in the past. When reading through [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) article, I encountered a few problems in the author's ModuleRewriter class, located about halfway down the article. The code inside the ModuleReWriter refers to objects that I cannot find and have no idea how to create myself.  These are:
-RewriterRuleCollection
-RewriterUtils
-Regex

Did I mess something up or is it the author's fault?

Comment: If you can I'd look at IIS7's rewrite rules. The newer rewrite rule generator is allot nicer then using ISAPI in my experience.

Comment: Did you download the source code for the article? Regex is a .NET class in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, but the other two were developed by the author.

Comment: Where is the source code for the article? I looked for it.